# SSRS VS2015 SSDT Report Wizard Style Selection Screen Not Showing

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am stumped on this one.  I am not sure if others are having the same issue.

In past versions, when I use the report wizard, one of the screens lets me choose the style (Slate, Forest...)

With my new setup the screen never appears and on the summary screen it says 'Style:Modern'

I tracked down the StyleTemplate.Xml, made a copy and changed 'Modern' to 'ModernTest'.  Both in the Styles folder and the en folder.  I have searched my c drive and these are the only two places this file exists.

EDIT:  I had to change the label to 'ModernTest' not the name.  Now 'ModernTest' is showing up in the summary.  I still however do not get the chance to change styles.

I added a new style to see if the page only shows up if more than one is present but maybe since that one was from an older version it still only thinks there is one valid style so skips the selection page...  I will try to replicate modern...

I am using VS2015 Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2, SSDT Version 14.0.1601.5

Anyone else have the same issue?

EDIT:  I copied an xml file from a previous version and now slate appears as the style.  I guess the only problem is that the screen to select the style no longer shows up.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with my installation of SSDT. When constructing the report through wizard, the section for style selection is missing. I'm using VS 2015 U2 & SSDT version 14.0.60525.

Comment: Me too... every #$%^ upgrade of the report designer beaks something...

Comment: In Visual Studio, Help, Send Feedback, Report a Problem, then type in "choose table style" and you'll see someone has added this issue, which you can vote up.